# Insert html code into Primefaces dialog using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying to insert dynamically html code inside a Primefaces dialog. The html code I want to append depends on the email body.

For example I want to add the below html code inside viewEmail div:

```
<h2>Resetting your Password</h2>
<p>Hi Juan Pablo Proverbio,</p>
<p>You've indicated that you've forgotten your password and would like to reset it. We've started the process by sending you a special code that you can use to reset your password.</p>
<p>In order to complete this process, copy the code below and go back to the page on the app or webpage when you started this process and enter the code in the place indicated on that page.</p>
<p>Here are your details:</p>
<p>email address: 
    <b>juanp@XXX</b>
</p>
<p>reset code: 
    <b>LxoAd5NM</b>
</p>
<p>Once you've entered this code you will be able to create a new password for your account.</p>
<p>If you've remembered your password, just ignore this code and keep using your current password. Please note that this code is only valid for 24 hours, so if you haven't used it by then you will need to start the process again. </p>
<p>If you didn't start this process by using a 'Forgot my Password' function on an app or website related to [Serv] then someone has done this using your email address. You can just ignore this email and your password won't be changed. If this keeps happening, please contact us.</p>
<p>Have a great day :)</p>
<p style="font-size:70%;">This email was sent to you because you are registered on [Serv] using the email address: juanp@XXX and someone requested a password reset for your account.</font></p>
```

and this is my view dialog:

```
<h:form id="viewEmailForm">
       <p:dialog header="Email viewer"
                 widgetVar="viewEmail" showEffect="puff" hideEffect="drop" width="600">

           <h:panelGrid columns="2">
               <p:outputLabel value="To"/>
               <p:outputLabel value="#{emailBean.selectedEmail.to}"/>

               <p:outputLabel value="From"/>
               <p:outputLabel value="#{emailBean.selectedEmail.from}"/>

               <p:outputLabel value="Subject"/>
               <p:outputLabel value="#{emailBean.selectedEmail.subject}"/>

               <p:outputLabel value="Email body"/>
               <div class="viewEmail">

               </div>

               <p:outputLabel value="Type"/>
               <p:outputLabel value="#{emailBean.selectedEmail.bodyType}"/>

               <p:outputLabel value="Retries"/>
               <p:outputLabel value="#{emailBean.selectedEmail.retries}"/>

               <p:outputLabel value="Last error"/>
               <p:outputLabel value="#{emailBean.selectedEmail.lastError}"/>

               <p:outputLabel value="Status"/>
               <p:outputLabel value="#{emailBean.selectedEmail.status}"/>

               <p:outputLabel value="Created info"/>
               <p:outputLabel value="#{emailBean.convertCreatedDate()}"/>

          </h:panelGrid>
          <f:facet name="footer">  
               <p:commandButton value="Close" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no"
                                    icon="ui-icon-close" onclick="PF('viewEmail').hide()" 
                                    style="float:right !important; margin-bottom: 10px !important"/> 
          </f:facet>
      </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

My current and poor jQuery script is:

```
<script id="viewEmailScript" type="text/javascript">
     $(".viewEmail").append( #{emailBean.selectedEmail.body} );
</script>
```

but It doesn't work.

Have you any suggestions how can I append this html code using jQuery from a primefaces component?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to render html code anyone just needs to add escape="false" in a primefaces outputLabel to append the value as html code.

```
<p:outputLabel value="#{emailBean.selectedEmail.body} " escape="false"/>
```

Thanks!